# Node Sequelize inserting wrong field position on many to many table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a many to many relationship between the tables DeliveryOrder and GasBottle with the extra field Amount, but when i try to insert some values in this table, sequelize change´s the field order.

My models:

```
const {Model,DataTypes} = require ('sequelize')

class GasBottle extends Model{
  static init(sequelize){
    super.init({
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      costPrice: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
      sellPrice: DataTypes.DOUBLE
    },{sequelize})
  }
  
  static associate({ DeliveryOrder,DeliveryOrderGasBottle}) {
   GasBottle.belongsToMany(DeliveryOrder, {
      through: DeliveryOrderGasBottle,
      as: "deliveryOrders",
      foreignKey: "deliveryOrderId",
    });
  }
}
module.exports = GasBottle
```

---

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

class DeliveryOrder extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        status: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        latitude: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        longitude: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        delivererId: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          references: {
            model: "Deliverer",
            key: "id",
          },
        },
      },
      { sequelize }
    );
  }

  static associate({ Deliverer, GasBottle, DeliveryOrderGasBottle }) {
    DeliveryOrder.belongsTo(Deliverer, { foreignKey: "delivererId" });
    DeliveryOrder.belongsToMany(GasBottle, {
      through: DeliveryOrderGasBottle,
      as: "bottles",
      foreignKey: "gasBottleId",
    });
  }
}

module.exports = DeliveryOrder;
```

---

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

class DeliveryOrderGasBottle extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        gasBottleId: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          references: {
            model: "GasBottle",
            key: "id",
          },
        },
        deliveryOrderId: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          references: {
            model: "DeliveryOrder",
            key: "id",
          },
        },

        amount: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
      { sequelize }
    );
  }
}
module.exports = DeliveryOrderGasBottle;
```

My migration file:

```
"use strict";
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable("DeliveryOrderGasBottle", {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      gasBottleId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "GasBottle",
          key: "id",
        },
        allowNull: false,
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
      },
      deliveryOrderId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "DeliveryOrder",
          key: "id",
        },
        allowNull: false,
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
      },
      amount:{
          type: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
          allowNull: false,
        },
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable("DeliveryOrderGasBottle");
  },
};
```

My association:

```
const deliveryOrder = await DeliveryOrder.create(obj);
  bottlesToAdd.map(async (bottle) => {
    const db_bottle = await GasBottle.findByPk(bottle.id);
    await deliveryOrder.addBottle(db_bottle, {
      through: { amount: parseInt(bottle.amount) },
    });
```

On insert, sequelize is changing the order of the ids, resulting in a constraint error because i dont have the id´s on the respective tables

```
INSERT INTO "DeliveryOrderGasBottle" ("gasBottleId","deliveryOrderId","amount","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (18,1,42,'2020-06-27 19:17:26.204 +00:00','2020-06-27 19:17:26.204 +00:00')
```